# i like to have a villager that trades a chestplate with a custom name that ignores attributes and damage value

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

[image: Damage Leggings III]
[image: Speed Helmet VI]
[image: Health Chestplate IV]

the villager buys these from players not selling them
i like to have them sell no matter what attribute value they have and damage

so players sell them to villagers listed by name(with the colors) and lore ignores all other values how can i do this?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: i have worked with custom villagers before and remember ignoring damage values before but i lost the code sense then and have no code to go from at this moment
have never tried this with attributes before

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is not possible to ignore damage values for items in a villager trade, because this damage value is not only used to indicate damage on a tool or a piece of armor, but also to indicate the color for a shulker box, and for item types, such as different saplings and different kinds of stone. Since these attributes get a default value when they are not specified, you are unable to ignore them.

Comment: what of the attributes like the speed damage and health on the pieces can one ignore those in a trade?

Comment: They should get ignored. Just try it!